# Equivalent of --same-as in xrandr in xorg.conf syntax (monitor as mirror of another)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, xorg.conf

I want to duplicate one monitor as a mirror of another. With `xrandr` all works but the changes are not permanent. I try to write the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf` to apply permanent changes. So the question is what is the equivalent of

```
xrandr --output "HDMI-0" --auto --same-as "DVI-D-0"
```

in xorg.conf.

This:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DVI-D-0"
    Option      "Primary" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "HDMI-0"
    Option      "SameAs" "VGA1"
EndSection
```

seems to do not work. In documentation of Xorg, I see `"LeftOf"`, `"RightOf"`, but not `"SameAs"`

Comment: As a workarround, you could use [this trick](https://markladoux.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/fixing-screen-resolution-for-gnome-and-gdm-on-fc19/)

Comment: We could ask a general question: is there anything to convert `xandr` config to `xorg.conf` config (script tool)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this hint:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "DVI"
    Device          "xxx"
    Monitor         "DVI-D-0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "HDMI"
    Device          "xxx"
    Monitor         "HDMI-0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DVI-D-0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "HDMI-0"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Screen         0 "DVI" 0 0
    Screen         1 "HDMI" 0 0
EndSection
```

Comment: What is "xxx"? What I have to replace in those occurrences of "xxx"? Thanks

Comment: The device to which Screen is tied to. I do not see your full configuration file. You can skip Screen sections in my example. You need Screen names to use in ServerLayout - you can see those in Xorg.0.log

Comment: I will try to find it out

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solutions for two screen sections and two monitor sections, and then... I was banging my head on the monitor until I tried this weird trick in `xorg.conf`, and it worked for me! Pay attention to the `"LeftOf"` options, it is all about them.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "eDP1_m"
    Option      "LeftOf" "HDMI1_m"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "HDMI1_m"
    Option      "LeftOf" "eDP1_m"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Device          "Card0"
    Monitor         "eDP1_m"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen1"
    Device          "Card0"
    Monitor         "HDMI1_m"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver     "Intel"
    BusID      "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Weird layout"
    Screen         0 "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen         1 "Screen1" 0 0
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DVI-D-0"
    Option      "Primary" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "HDMI-0"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
EndSection
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).